# Extract multiple values from a string via regex

Tags: regex, python-re

I have a number of strings from a 3rd party data source that are in various lengths that contain both underscore and spaces. Each portion of the string is important and I am trying to break it apart into various fields via `python`. The string does not have special characters (`\n`, `\t`, etc.) - should just be spaces, underscores,  and parentheses are used to break the data parts.

| String | Year | State | ID | Sub ID | Extra1 | Extra2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022_UT_T1000_100 (Classification1 Classification2) | 2022 | UT | T1000 | 100 | Classification1 | Classification2 |
| 2021_TX_V999_005 (Classification1) | 2021 | TX | V999 | 005 | Classification1 |  |
| 1999_GA_123456_7890 | 1999 | GA | 123456 | 7890 |  |  |

I could split the string by the underscore, then split the last field by a space but that seems error-prone. `Regex` is likely the best approach.

I can match the year using this: `^[1-9]\d{3,}$`. However, when trying to add an OR operator, it will only find the underscore.

Is there a way to extract this data when I know a pattern exists?

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen python and I updated the question. Actually didn't know language mattered with regex.

Comment: Is this a Pandas data frame, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is a dataframe - trying to blow the string out to other columns.

Comment: Is the first string in your example `'2022_UT_T1000_100 (Classification1 Classification2)'` or `2022_UT_T1000_100\n(Classification1\n Classification2)`' or something else?

Comment: @CarySwoveland spaces not `\n`

Comment: I suggest you clarify that in your question. Could `(Classification1 Classification2)` be instead `(Classification 1 Classification2)`, or can we assume there are one or two words between the parentheses, (separated by one or more spaces if two) and no space after `'('` or before `')'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the suggestion. Updated. I can see why that's confusing with the break in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `str.extract` with the regex pattern:

```regex
^(\d{4})_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_ ]+)(?: \((\S+)(?: (\S+))?\))?$
```

Note that this pattern assumes that there would only be three variants in the string column, namely no extras, one extra, or at most two extras.  For arbitrary number of words in parentheses, we would need a different approach.

Python script:

```py
df[["Year", "State", "ID", "Sub ID", "Extra1", "Extra2"]] = df["String"].str.extract(r'^(\d{4})_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_ ]+)(?: \((\S+)(?: (\S+))?\))?$')
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySkpzP/1) showing that the pattern is working for all variants of your string column.